# Who's in charge of Centurion-only ship?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

At the end of *Battlestar Galactica* (2004) they set Centurions free and give them their own ship, saying that they should find their own destiny, and then they just jump from Earth.

So who's in charge? How do they decide what to do, what's their goal, where to go?

Do they act as a hive-mind or something?

Comment: Like the show said, they were left to forge their own destiny and their own future. Rather than put one in charge, they likely worked as a collective, deciding where to go next. It’s made clear they can interface with the base ship’s navigation system and the hybrid that runs it, so it’s likely they have to work as a collective anyway to go anywhere. They may also have seen humanity’s hierarchical command structure and decided that could lead to bad things like it did for the humans, so they chose a “flat” hierarchy structure instead where everyone agrees where to go and what to do next.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan post this as answer.

Comment: My comment is mostly speculation from my understanding from the show, without much source, which is why I commented. Just wanted to be in line with the community guidelines.